# MEAN stack update view with Node/Express response

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have a MEAN stack dashboard app *(server1)* that communicates with a nodejs/express server *(server2)* which makes queries to a mongoDB. For example the user is supposed to select a month via the dashboard app calendar and this date will be sent to the nodejs/express server that will query mongo and return for example the number of times you went to the gym during that month.

I am getting the right response but I have problems updating the view (since http requests are asynchronous the request in the response in executed faster and thus updates my view with the wrong value)

I tackled my request as follows:

*dashboard app - angular frontend*

```
$scope.query = function () {
        console.log("I am hereee");
        var month = ("0" + ($scope.dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var date = $scope.dt.getFullYear() + "" + month;
        var queryData = JSON.stringify({MemberID_Hash: $scope.memberNo, Date_Key_Month: date});
        console.log("data: ", queryData);
        console.log("url: ", expressQuery);
        $http({ //send query to node/express server
            method: 'POST',
            url: expressQuery,
            data: queryData,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        }).then(function(response) { //read backend response
            console.log (">>>>>>>>");
            $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "http://localhost:9000/sendToController"
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
              console.log("responde.data: ", response.data);
              $scope.nrOfSwipes = response.data;
            }, function myError(response) { });
        });
    };
```

*dashboard app - back-end in express*

```
var dataController = "test"; // used a global variable to save the response value to update my view (bad design => thus, any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated)

module.exports = function(app) {

    // receives the response from server2 - !! this is executed 2nd
    app.post('/getQueryJson', function(request, response) {
        if(response.statusCode == 200) { 

          console.log("In routes.js TESTING......")
          console.log("This is your request: ", request.body);

          dataController = request.body;
          console.log("dataController1: ", dataController);
          response.send(request.body);
        }else{
          response.send(" Error code: " + response.statusCode);
        }
    });

    // updates the view - !! this is executed first
    app.post('/sendToController', function(request, response) {
        console.log("dataController2: ", dataController);
        response.send(dataController);
    });
};
```

The problem is the request takes longer to process and so my response which calls *sendToController* is executed first then *getQueryJson*.
Any idea how I can change the way they are executed? or any idea if it possible I can send the response from */getQueryJson* directly to the frontend controller without having to make another request to */sendToController*?

I just started getting my hands on the MEAN stack so I realise this may sound like a basic question but I am really stuck.

Comment: You can always check your routes with Postman too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you've chained promises, the order differs for you because you're not returning `Promise`. Editing your code to enforce order.

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: expressQuery,
  data: queryData,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  }
}).then(() => {
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',  //read backend response
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/sendToController'
  });
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(`responde.data: ${response.data}`);
  $scope.nrOfSwipes = response.data;
}).catch((err) => {
  //if error occurs
  console.log('err', err.stack);
});
```

Examining your code further, I see that, call to `sendToController` doesn't take any input from `getQueryJson`. If that's the actual case. You can use `Promise.all()` on that.

Making this changes to your code.

```
Promise.all([
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: expressQuery,
    data: queryData,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
  }),
  $http({
    method: 'POST',  //read backend response
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/sendToController'
  })
]).then((responses)=> {
  let ctrlResponse = responses[1];
  console.log(`responde.data: ${ctrlResponse.data}`);
  $scope.nrOfSwipes = ctrlResponse.data;
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('err', err.stack);
});
```

> or any idea if it possible I can send the response from /getQueryJson directly to the frontend controller without having to make another request to /sendToController?

Yes. We can do that. You need to respond with object in json. But the code you've provided us seem to be placeholders. If you can merge them. It might look like

```
response.status(200).send({
    query: 'some string', // your getQueryJson response,
    controller: 'some more value' //sendToController
});
```